# How to begin client server programming in c#

Tags: c#, client-server, backend

I'm looking for a 'how to' about "client/server" programming in C#. A search returns a lot of things but not close enough to what I'm looking for.

If there is a good 'how to' which describes how to start programming a client/server application please let me know, or could anyone recommend a book about the topic?

Here some additional informations:

The application will have multiple parts like chat, voice service and in addition some calculations e.g. random loot. Most of the features should be available on a web portal, and or via mobile app.

So the used protocol will be TCP/IP.

Comment: Have a read around http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks for that info.

Comment: "what I'm looking for"? What would that be? What kind of client/server. What protocol? What use case? If you don't specify, then there's no way to avoid the same problem with the recommendations that you are now facing. Ultimately, this question is off-topic for SO because you're asking for off-site resources. It would also qualify as too broad. Waaaay too broad.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: strange that on a Plattform like this an opinion is not allowed in this case a opionnated answer is better then none. for me it is sad that trying to get exact that Kind of answer is rated down cause someone could not understand that an hint/clue or just opion is the needed anwser. but as i mentioned in some comments i'll have a look on those link an found one which gives me exact that clues i needed. thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net, you really should start learning WCF if you want to do server/client programming.
Try these resources:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows
2. http://www.wcftutorial.net/

You can move to more core programming like socket programming or implementing your own version of a REST based service without using WCF after you grasp some WCF.

WCF basically helps you with a lot of plumbing and helps you to get a good headstart.

Comment: thanks for those links i'll have a look on those.

Answer (score 0):

Read my articles on the subject:

- [Network Programming: Networking Theory](http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/05/network-programming-networking-theory.html)
- [C# Network Programming: Echo Client/Server](http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/05/c-network-programming-echo-clientserver.html)
- [C# Network Programming: Simple HTTP Client](http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/05/c-network-programming-simple-http-client.html)

Comment: thanks for those info i'll check them out